# setTimeout functions with 0, 0, 0 in sequence but also 0,1,0 how?

Tags: javascript

I just tried executing below code

```
 setTimeout(function(){ console.log(1); }, 0);
 setTimeout(function(){ console.log(2); }, 0);
 setTimeout(function(){ console.log(3); }, 0);
```

Above code has logged 1, 2, 3 in sequence. But if I do the same thing with seconds values 0, 1, 1

```
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(1); }, 0);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(2); }, 1);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(3); }, 0);
```

Still the above code logs same 1, 2, 3 in sequence. Tested this in Chrome!

Would like to know whether this is happening due to `console.log()`. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Change the 1 tot 1000. You'll see that it won't go in sequence. It's due to the processing speed.

Comment: I guess it's because 1 ms is really a little interval, it's about the time of processing the setTimeout.

Comment: @Fietsband Yes, even if I change it to `2` still it behaves as you said.

Comment: 1 ms is too fast, but apparently 2 ms isn't. I just tested that on Chrome. There isn't anything wrong with the code, it's just the processing time delay.

Comment: setTimeout does not take into account time needed to create timeout. If function start is impossible at the moment, then all timeouts put in query and wait until engine will find enough cpu time.

Comment: @RobinCarlier Yes, I think so. So does it mean that using 0, 1, milliseconds are ignorant?

Comment: Firefox does not behave that way. Firefox always honors timeout delay ordering even if it rounds the timeout value up to the minimum interval. (Firefox logs "1 3 2" in the second case, in other words.)

Comment: @Pointy Could you please give reasons how timers are treated by different browsers.?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers just leave it here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML standard does not require user agents to strictly order queued timer events by their intended wait time when said wait time has already elapsed.  It is very likely that the third call to `setTimeout`, returning to native code, and running the first JS callback from the event loop takes more than 1 ms, so running the second callback immediately upon re-entering the event loop next is just as logical as running the third.

Comment: Delays less that 4ms are treated as 4ms delays.

Comment: @Pointy looking at the Chromium source https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/frame/DOMTimer.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=104&rcl=1415147671 it definitely shows timeouts less than 4ms being coerced to 4ms, but there's a demonstrable difference in behaviour (in Chrome desktop current) when calling from JS with a timeout of 2 or more vs. a shorter value.  This suggests to me that there's some other code at play, though I can't find it in the Chromium source.

Comment: @yjo That's interesting. I discovered that Firefox honors the original requested values some time ago, but I don't think I checked any other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of context-switching in an operating system is typically greater than 1ms (expect 5-10ms or so); therefore, you cannot expect a difference of 1ms to be noticeable.

Notwithstanding the above, in terms of your browser's JavaScript engine, historically speaking and now officially as of HTML5, [any difference below 4ms is likely to be ignored](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout) anyway:

> [Historically](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=792#c10) browsers implement setTimeout() "clamping": successive
>   `setTimeout()` calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit
>   are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay,
>   `DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE`, is 4 ms (stored in a preference in Firefox:
>   `dom.min_timeout_value`), with a `DOM_CLAMP_TIMEOUT_NESTING_LEVEL` of 5ms.
>
> In fact, 4ms is [specified by the HTML5 spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#timers) and is consistent across
>   browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 /
>   Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested
>   timeouts was 10 ms.
>
> In addition to "clamping", the timeout can also fire later when the
>   page (or the OS/browser itself) is busy with other tasks.

With all the timers firing during the same event tick, then, the only remaining ordering to go on is the order in which the timers were set, which results in `1, 2, 3`. Some browsers though, like Firefox, do honour the implicit ordering implied by the requested delays (even when those delays are rounded up to the same value) and in those browsers you will see `1, 3, 2`.

Answer (score -1):

Some browsers, e.g. older versions of Internet Explorer don't support timer resolutions under 10ms, so they would treat a 1ms timeout the same a 0ms.

Comment: Yes, but not everyone is using an HTML5-compliant browser yet.

Comment: You've entirely missed the point, which is that this is not some historical footnote that happens only in older browsers. If anything, it's _more_ common now than it was in the olden days. That's the polar opposite of what your answer claims.